# How to catch JAX-RS exceptions in JBoss EAP 5 when XML is unparsable?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-rs, jboss6.x

I have a web service application (using JAX-RS) running on JBoss EAP 5 with Apache in front of it.
My class that XML is being marshaled to looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "newRequest")
public class NewRequest {
    @XmlElement(required = false, name = "Guid")
    public String guid;
    @XmlElement(required = false, name = "AuthorizedBy")
    public String authorizedBy;
}
```

and the actual code that handles requests:

```
@Path("/newrequest")
public class NewResource {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NewResource.class);

    @PUT
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public String processNewRequest(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization, NewRequest request) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I see the request in the Apache access_log:

```
10.1.4.55 - qa [26/Jun/2013:13:34:16 -0500] "PUT /rest/newrequest HTTP/1.1" 400 961 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.2.1 (java 1.5)" 135807 961
```

but nothing in the JBoss logs. That 400 error is produced when I intentionally misspelled something in my XML (using JMeter to send request; put 'nwe' instead of 'new'.
Is there any way for me to catch this error and maybe find out which element is a bad one? I did read about JAX-RS exception mappers, but never used them before, and not sure if they are the right way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be handling this exception with an `ExceptionMapper`.

Exception mappers are easy to create and configure in JAX-RS.  All you have to do is implement the `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper<T>` interface and annotate the class with the `@Provider` annotation.

```
@Provider
public class ParseExceptionMapper extends implements ExceptionMapper<{Exception Being Thrown During Parse}> 
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse({Exception Being Thrown During Parse} exception) 
    {
         //Create a response here.
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I assume you are using Resteasy as your JAX-RS implementation since you only mentioned you are deploying in JBoss.  Not that it really matters since the `BadRequestException` is in any JAX-RS compliant implementation.

Try creating an ExceptionMapper implementation for `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException`.  That is the exception that Resteasy raises when it encounters an HTTP 400 error.

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException;

@Provider
public class BadRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException>
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(BadRequestException exception) 
    {
        //Create Response Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, but that is part of my problem, there is no exception being thrown, or at least not that I can see... I am using log4j and there is nothing in the jBoss logs... The only way I know it was not successful, is that 400 error in Apache access.log I think something happens in JAX-RS code (in the .jar) that is not being exposed to me.

Comment: @Mike - I updated my answer above.  Try creating an exception mapper that handles org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException. Example above.